# Oauth 2.0 redirect to app after auth on server

Tags: node.js, web-applications, oauth-2.0

I'm very new to web development, and am trying to implement authorization through a 3rd party for my app. Since I'm testing, the app as well as the server are both hosted locally. I have Oauth2.0 set up to authorize with github so that when I access the server (port 2), it asks for github auth then redirects to the app on port 1 with a code (the token is still null). However, if I go directly to the app hosted on port 1, I do not need to authenticate and there is no code given. Ideally, when the user goes to the app URL, they are redirected to github authentication, then back to the app.

I do not need to use the github API, I only want to use the github account login to authenticate and access the app.

API/server: localhost:3002
App: localhost:3001

```
const clientId = '...'
const clientSecret = '...'
const redirectUri = 'localhost:3001'

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('authorizing client through github...')
    res.redirect(`https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=${clientId}`);
});
...
const axios = require('axios');
let token = null;

app.get('/oauth-callback', (req, res) => {
  const body = {
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    redirect_uri: redirectUri,
    code: req.query.code
  };

  const opts = { headers: { accept: 'application/json' } };
  axios.post(`https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token`, body, opts).
    then(res => res.data['access_token']).
    then(_token => {
      console.log('My token:', token);
      token = _token;
      res.json({ ok: 1 });
    }).
    catch(err => res.status(500).json({ message: err.message }));
});
```

Apologies if this is a simple question, the Oauth docs aren't very helpful.